# use gridlayout programatically and set layoutparams (weight)

Tags: android, layoutparams

I set `layoutparams` with this syntax

```
gridParams= new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(
                    GridLayout.UNDEFINED,(float) 1.0),
                    GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,(float) 1.0));
```

But it does not work properly.
Also, this code works correctly for the support library GridLayout and I tested the code with the device that has android 5.0.2(api 21)

Comment: What is not working properly? show what is expected and what you are getting.

Comment: I want to divide the gridlayout space into equal parts (with weight)